# FormEncode validate: words divided by a comma

Tags: python, pylons, formencode

How to validate words divided by a comma by FormEncode ?

Something like this:

```
"foo1, foo2, foo3" -> ["foo1", "foo2", "foo3"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably need a [custom validator](http://formencode.org/Validator.html#writing-your-own-validator).  Here's a quick example:

```
import formencode

class CommaSepList(formencode.validators.FancyValidator):

    def _to_python(self, value, state):
        return value.split(",")

    def validate_python(self, value, state):
        for elem in value:
            if elem == "": 
                raise formencode.Invalid("an element of the list is empty", value, state) 

>>> CommaSepList.to_python("1,2,3")
['1', '2', '3']
>>> CommaSepList.to_python("1,,")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.5/site-packages/FormEncode-1.2.3dev-py2.5.egg/formencode/api.py", line 416, in to_python
    vp(value, state)
  File "myValidator.py", line 17, in validate_python
    raise formencode.Invalid("an element of the list is empty", value, state)
```

Of course, you'll want to add validation specific to your use case.

Comment: This approach is often best when piped through a list comprehension.  e.g.  `[j for j in [i.strip() for i in value.split(",")] if j]`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming each word is separated by a comma and a space (`', '`):

```
>>> x = "foo1, bar2, foo3"
>>> x.split(', ')
['foo1', 'bar2', 'foo3']
```

And then pass that list on to FormEncode and have it do whatever you need it to do.